# Send multiple attachments with JQuery and wp_mail() function

Tags: jquery, uploads, wp-mail

I need to add the ability to have multiple attachments from the input field on my Wordpress site. Currently I used jQuery code to clone the input field and assign new ID and name with increment of 1.

The problem is no matter how many attachments I upload and send, only the first one gets delivered in mailbox. I checked Wordpress codex and found wp_mail function that should do what I need, but I need tweak it for taking multiple attachments. Code below:

```
    $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
    $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail( 'test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );



    jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    var cloneCount = 1;
    var cloneCount2 = 1;
    jQuery('.file-upload').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#file-image')
       .clone()
       .attr({id: 'file-image'+ cloneCount++, name: 'file-image'+ cloneCount2++})
       .insertAfter(jQuery('[id^=file-image]:last'))
    }); 
 });

    <span class="file-upload">
       <input name="file-image" size="40" id="file-image" aria-invalid="false" type="file">
    </span>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you try this plugin?
[Multifile Upload Field for Contact Form 7](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/multifile-upload-field-for-contact-form-7/)

Comment: I know it but haven't tried it yet, from what I read it zips the attachments. Might try if all other solutions fail. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I will stick with your answer for now.